# How to check if a document exists without retrieving it: Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose to connect to MongoDB and perform CRUD operations on it. One of my collections has a lot of data in its individual documents (records). At a point in my code, I want to check if a document with particular `id` field exists already in the collection, and if it does, then I can show a proper error to the user.

Currently, I am using the `findOne()` method available in the `Mongoose` library. The problem with this method (or any other `find` prefixed methods)
is that it retrieves the data, which takes a bit time if there is a crazy bunch of data stored.

I am looking for a way to get some kind of `boolean` as a result indicating if the document exists or not, without actually getting the whole document itself.

Comment: You could carry on using findOne(), and then in the callback check the length of the returned data before you carry on doing any operations? I don't believe there's any exact way to check if something exists without completing a query for it. Alternatively you could use countDocuments() to check the number of documents in the query? This will just count the number rather than returning it?

Comment: You can add a `.lean()` to findOne to get a faster response https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use countDocuments() to check the number of documents in the query? This will just count the number rather than returning it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass id in `findOne()`

Make a one common function.

```
const objectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
getMongoObjectId(id) {   
    return new objectID(id)
}
```

Now just call function

```
findOne({_id:common.getMongoObjectId('ID value hear')})
```

It will same as `where` condition in mysql.

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for answering. How can I use the `ObjectId`, where can I get that function?